# My code shows invalid literal for float()

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

**This is my code in editor:**

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import numpy as np

x,y = np.loadtxt('D:\Tanjil\Python\directory\Matplot_trial1.csv',
                 unpack=True , delimiter='\s')

plt.plot(x,y,'r',label='angle=30 Degree'),

plt.ylabel('Power Input (kW)'),

plt.xlabel('Speed(rpm)'),

plt.axis([750.0, 1400.0, 3.3,3.8])

plt.title('Power Input vs. Speed curve')

plt.legend()

plt.show()
```

**then it shows this:**

```
  File "<ipython-input-19-abec5f4efd27>", line 6, in <module>
    unpack=True , delimiter='\s')

  File "C:\Users\bad_tanjil\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\npyio.py", line 860, in loadtxt
    items = [conv(val) for (conv, val) in zip(converters, vals)]

ValueError: invalid literal for float(): 1350,3.64
```

Comment: Can you, maybe, give an example file, structured the same way like 'D:\Tanjil\Python\directory\Matplot_trial1.csv' for more detailed help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to read a csv document with `delimiter='\s'`, but the dcument contains `1350,3.64` somewhere, which are two numbers clearly not whitespace separated. Check your csv, the error originates from there. If it's comma separated, use `delimiter=','`.

Also, `\s` doesn't mean whitespace separated, it means separated by a literal `\s`, whitespace separated is the default when you don't set a delimiter.

Answer (score 1):

You should call `plt.axis()` with a list of integers like this :

```
plt.axis([750, 1400, 3, 4])
```

Comment: But I'm trying to plot a csv file which has a data (1350,3.64). I think some error is there .

Comment: The problem comes from your .csv file, numpy try to convert `1350,3.64` to float. Maybe should you use a different delimiter.